# From base extract regex match from character vector

Tags: regex, r

Say I have a character vector test:

```
test = c("2014-03-02","2012-09-08","2010-12-11")
```

And I want the result to be the years in numeric like so:

```
c(2014,2012,2010)
```

How do I do this in an 'easy' way? Currently the following works fine, but is not very 'pretty':

```
test    = c("2014-03-02","2012-09-08","2010-12-11")
tmp     = strsplit(test,split="-")
myYears = as.numeric(unlist(lapply(tmp, function(x) x[[1]])))
```

I am sure this can be done in a different way using regex "\d{4}" in some way?

Answer (score 3):

You can just try:

```
as.numeric(substr(test,1,4))
```

Or:

```
as.numeric(gsub("^([0-9]{4}).+$","\\1",test))
```

Another option:

```
as.numeric(strftime(test,format="%Y"))
```

Or:

```
as.POSIXlt(test)$year+1900
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sub` function. Just replace all the chars from the first `-` until the last with an empty string.

```
> test = c("2014-03-02","2012-09-08","2010-12-11")
> sub("-.*", "", test)
[1] "2014" "2012" "2010"
> as.numeric(sub("-.*", "", test))
[1] 2014 2012 2010
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/fJ6cR4/13)

Comment: I get "This webpage is not available" on link

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanx a lot :) is there an online site where you run this or you have it on ur system?

Answer (score 0):

why not just do the following, which accomplishes everything you are doing in one line:

```
as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(test, "-"), '[', 1))
```

this 1. splits the vector using - 2. select the first item and simplifies it to a vector 3. converts it to numeric

Answer (score 0):

```
test = c("2014-03-02","2012-09-08","2010-12-11")

years <- as.numeric(regmatches(test , regexpr("^\\d+" , test)))
```

## Explanation

```
test = c("2014-03-02","2012-09-08","2010-12-11")

# this function return two things
# 1. The index of the first match for this regular expression
# 2. the length of characters that matches our regular expressions 
indices <- regexpr("^\\d+" , test)
# [1] 1 1 1
#attr(,"match.length")
#[1] 4 4 4

# 1. in this case the index of our first match is the first character for each date
# as you see in the result it returns 1
# 2. our regular expression matches 4 didgits from the beginning of string 
# so the length in this case is 4


# then we have now indices variable which represents the index of the first matched 
# character , and how many characters it matches  starting from the first match , 
# then pass this to regmatches function
# this will use the result of indices to to get only the matched part from our input
matches <- regmatches(test , indices)
# [1] "2014" "2012" "2010"

# Look again at indices variable , regmatches() will substring 
# the input starting from the first index , and how many characters 
# it will substring ? only 4 characters based on the result we get from 
# indices variables
```

Hope this clarifies the code

Comment: Perhaps an explanation would be helpful?

Comment: Hi @BenBlack I've added explanation in my answer check it

Answer (score 0):

Even if you asked for a `base R` solution, I just wanted to let you know that there is a very easy way to extract the year directly as `numeric` using function `year` from [package `lubridate`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html):

```
test = c("2014-03-02","2012-09-08","2010-12-11")

library(lubridate)    
year_test <- year(test)

year_test
#[1] 2014 2012 2010
is.numeric(year_test)
# [1] TRUE
```